What assumptions does this Kaplan-Meier thought experiment violate?
I have been thinking about how a naive logistic regression assuming censored subjects were still alive will always overestimate a survival proportion compared to the product-limit estimate, at a particular point in follow-up time.
But then how do I rationalise this absurd example (I presume fundamental assumptions around censoring are being broken)?
Imagine you have 100 subjects that you follow for (almost) 100 days. On the 99th day, 99 people drop out of the study and on the 100th day the last person left, died. By the product-limit estimator, survival would be 0%, right? (i.e. the event rate (cumulative incidence) would be 100%.
But in reality, survival is essentially 99% and the event rate only 1%. And you get closer to the truth with a logistic regression incorrectly assuming those censored were still alive at the end of the study.
I assume I am not thinking about things properly, but interested to be corrected.

The Kaplan-Meier estimate is of survival as a function of time. In your case, survival would be 100% until the time of that final event. That’s a pretty good summary of the situation you describe.
Furthermore, the drop to 0% survival at that time is consistent with your data. Everyone still known to be at risk at that time died. In practice, that censoring pattern might well represent informative censoring, which would violate the assumptions needed for proper interpretation.
This does raise the practical problems of empirical survival curves at late times. They can show quite weird behaviors when few remain at risk. Your example might be extreme, but it’s of the same kind. Don’t trust these curves at very late times. Show the numbers still at risk over time, along with the survival curve, so your audience can interpret properly.
